# how to get read and unread message list using gmail api javascript

Tags: javascript, php, gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

How to get difference read and unread from mail list's using Gamil api javascript.i have used gmail api v1 javascript, but it's display overall rows list.

Thanks,

Comment: Try this url : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/release-notes and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels

Answer (score 0):

When [listing messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), you can give a custom search query in the `q` query parameter. Just set the value to `is:unread` to get unread messages, or `!is:unread` to get read messages:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is%3Aunread&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1565ad3af8dbd82e",
   "threadId": "1565ad3af8dbd82e"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me:
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{yourgmailid}/messages?q=is:unread

In headers:-
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 
Accept : application/json